# Maven plugin CLI parameter overwriting <configuration> in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

How does/should Maven plugins behave with regards to the order in which they process configuration options? I would expect that properties passed via CLI overwrite those defined in a `<configuration>` block in `pom.xml`.

Here's an example.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <executions>
    ...
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <url>foo.com</url>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**CLI**

```
mvn group:artifact:1.2.3:doit -Dmymojo.url=bar.com
```

I am currently debugging a plugin (not mine) that gives precedence to the `url` value defined in the POM rather than the one passed on the CLI. Is that how mojos are supposed to behave i.e. a Maven feature rather than a plugin bug? I didn't find anything mentioned in the ref guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4979 this works as designed. I find it counter-intuitive and don't find the reasons given in MNG-4979 convincing.

If your setup allows to modify the `pom.xml` you can work around this behavior as suggested by JF Meier (and the issue above).

```
<properties>
  <mymojo.url>foo.bar</mymojo.url>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <executions>
    ...
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <url>${mymojo.url}</url>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Through the command line, you set a *property* `url`. This would override an entry `<url>foo.com</url>` in the `<properties>` section of the POM.

Many plugins allow to set configuration entries through properties, but these properties do not automatically have the same name. In the documentation, this is usually called *user property*. To see examples, look e.g. at

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I made sure to use the correct mojo property name. If I remove the `<configuration>` section from the POM everything works as expected. I'll update the Q to avoid this potential confusion.

Comment: I would expect the command line property to override the configuration property (which is the expected behavioiur), but in the end, it is up to the plugin to implement that. To solve that particular problem, you can set the configuration entry `<url>` to `${url}`, and define a `<url>` property in the POM.

Comment: A quick look at the plugin source code probably reveals how the `url` parameter is resolved.

Comment: I did that prior to posting here and as I didn't see anything fishy about it I concluded it could be standard Maven behavior (however illogical it feels): https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/liquibase/maven/plugins/AbstractLiquibaseMojo.java#L61

Comment: Ok, you have done your homework. And I don't know any further reason why this behaviour appears...

Comment: Just found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4979 -> intended behavior obviously.

Comment: @MarcelStör Thank you very much, I learned something new today. This means that my answer is not really very useful ... it would probably be a good idea if you put your comment (with the linked issue) into a separate answer, and I'll delete mine.

Comment: I did and I'll accept my own answer once the 24h grace period imposed by SO is over. However, I suggest you leave your answer in place.